# prevent multiple login with same login credentials in php

Tags: php, database

My website has premium videos, for which users have to pay to watch it. I am sending a random user name and password to the user's email id when the payment is completed. Then I want to assure no more than one user use that login credentials simultaneously. For that I use a login_status column in database table with login credentials and change it to 1 when one user login and change to 0 when user log out. But the problem is, if the user close browser or network connection loss may happened will not update database. Then login_status will be 1 undefinitely and no one can use that login credentials again.

Is there any idea to accomplish my task?

Comment: Are they streaming videos ? Could you not stop sending the video if someone tries to log to an account while you are playing a video for the same account ?

Comment: Actually I didn't get what you meant. Can you make it clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you write a timestamp into the database when the user logs in. You might have some logic to periodically update this value if the user is still logged in - for example, the page  could make an AJAX request every 5 minutes to update the value or something.

Then, if the value is older than a certain threshold (say, 1 hour) you can allow a duplicate login through - which of course will reset the timestamp and prevent anyone else from accessing.

Comment: What if I decide to prevent the AJAX script from executing ? I'll be logged, and can stay logged and watch the videos, just have to wait to log from somewhere else and so on, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom session handler. The right place to store the data is alongside the session information - and you get the benefits of fully automatic garbage collection.

You might also want to combine this with using a cookie with a fixed (but updating) expiry time - so users can resume their session after closing their browsers rather than having to wait for the garbage collection to reap the expired session.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically (hourly?) go through the database and change all of the login_statuses to 0.

Change it back to 1 when the user uses the site for whatever reason.

That way, no one will be locked out for more than 1 hour at a time.